# Incoming email problem

Tags: email

I am running a MacBook Pro 15", system 10.12.3. My incoming email doesn't come in, but outgoing is no problem. Mobile devices, iPhone, iPad, use same email and have no problem. Settings are the same on all devices. I tried to replace Apple mail, but get the message that it cannot be done because it is needed by the system. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on a corporate or school network, or is this at home? If at home, do you have any specific rules configured on your router?

Comment: I'd check to make sure your incoming mail server records are correct. If you're using a common email like gmail or yahoo then you can google for the correct addresses to place in those fields.